# Calculate days in interface

Tags: sql, sql-server

`Hello everybody,
I have table as : 
ID----DateStarted----Monthly/Quarter 
1-----22/3/2022-------Monthly------ 
2-----25/3/2022--------Quarter----- 
3-----28/3/2022--------Quarter----- 
4-----2/12/2022---------Monthly----

I need output: (I suppose current day : 3/5/2022)

ID----DateStarted----Monthly/Quarter------NumDays-----State
1-----22/3/2022-------22/4/2022------------30---------Late
2-----25/3/2022--------25/6/2022-----------90---------OK
3-----28/3/2022--------28/6/2022-----------90---------OK
4-----2/12/2022---------2/1/2023-----------30---------OK

I know number of days in monthly which different !
How can i get output above in sql server ?

Thank you so much !

`

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? In >=2012 you can use `EOMONTH`. Also, why does row 4 report 30 days (I assume '2/12/2022' means 'February')?

Comment: Now do you calculate the `NumDays` ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you just want to add a month when monthly, and 3 months when quarterly, than you can use something like this

```
select t.id,
       t.datestarted,
       t.[Montly/Quarter],
       datediff(day, t.datestarted, t.[Montly/Quarter]) as NumDays,
       case when t.[Montly/Quarter] < convert(date, getdate()) then 'Late'
            else 'OK'
       end as State
from   ( select temp.id,
                temp.datestarted,
                case when datetype = 'Monthly' then dateadd(month, 1, temp.datestarted)
                     when datetype = 'Quarter' then dateadd(month, 3, temp.datestarted)
                end as [Montly/Quarter]     
         from   test temp
      ) t
```

See [this DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e2afdc54f746981ff22f76fa60817304)

However, the outcome is not as in your expected result for the NumDays, you need to be more clear about how you got to exact those results.

| id | datestarted | Montly/Quarter | NumDays | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-03-22 | 2022-04-22 | 31 | Late |
| 2 | 2022-03-25 | 2022-06-25 | 92 | OK |
| 3 | 2022-03-28 | 2022-06-28 | 92 | OK |
| 4 | 2022-12-02 | 2023-01-02 | 31 | OK |